# oData, REST and Web API in asp.net

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, odata, restful-architecture

I am new to these concepts so I just wanted help on some simple information to get started with ASP.NET Web API and oData.

I have been searching in google and for sure I am getting lots of resources but a little confused where to start from.

I have gone through the information w.r.t difference between a traditional web service and a web API.

I request you to give me information/any useful articles to get started with on below:

1. Real Life example of Web API - I read somewhere that Paypal is the best example. Is it correct? Any other easy examples which help me in relating Web API with our day to day life?
2. What is oData and how we can leverage this with Web API? Why do we need oData?
3. What is Restful and real life usage (example) of the same.

Please note I am a beginner in this area, my questions might be very basic, kindly bear with me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Web Api,  Microsoft Virtual Academy can be a good start. Because they are covering web api with Odata, so here is the link

[Web Api Jump Start in Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/web-api-design-jump-start-8689/)

Comment: Thank You, will definitely go through this right away.